# Remove values from array depending on conditions

Tags: php, algorithm

This is more of an algorithm problem than a PHP problem, but I can't seem to figure it out!

I've got a multi dimensional array as following :

```
[
    210875 => ["2", "1"],
    129096 => ["2", "2"]
]
```

There are 2 ids but there could be more. I want to keep in my table only 1 id depending on these conditions.

Pseudo code:

```py
if a[0] == 1 and a[1] >= 1: # the id gets deleted right away without looking at other conditions
if a[0] >= 2 and a[1] == 2: # it stays if nothing below fits else it gets deleted
if a[0] >= 3 and a[1] == 3: # it stays if nothing below fits else it gets deleted
if a[0] >= 8 and a[1] == 4: # it stays if nothing below fits else it gets deleted
# ... etc
```

If two fit the same conditions then one of them randomly gets deleted.

For example (pseudo code):

```py
a[0] == 2 and a[1] == 1
a[0] == 2 and a[1] == 2
```

I've tried doing the following, but I can't figure out how to dynamically have if-conditions made dependent on my algorithm :

```
$sub_array = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    if($v[0] == 1 && $v[1] == 1) continue;
    if($v[0] >= 2 && $v[1] == 2) $sub_array[$k] = $v;
    if($v[0] >= 6 && $v[1] == 3) $sub_array[$k] = $v;
    if($v[0] >= 8 && $v[1] == 4) $sub_array[$k] = $v;
    // etc ...
}
```

Also, when I do that, how to know which one is the highest in my sub array?

Comment: I don't mind getting downvoted if they're followed by an explanation ! :)

Comment: So write a foreach loop and test each sub arrays occurances as you go. Then create a new array with the ones you want to keep.

Comment: @RiggsFolly isn't that a bit too unclean? Isn't here a simpler way? That's what I thought about.

Comment: You will get a better response from the community if you show us some code where you have attempted to code this. Otherwise it just looks like a DIFM request

Comment: Its so much simpler than trying to unset parts of an array you are actually processing to make the decision to remove bits of it

Comment: You can always unset the original array once the loop is finished to clean up and reduce your memory footprint

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, I updated my question with a specific question in my edit ! :)

Comment: `$v[1] = 2` etc. is assigning 2 rather than testing equal to 2.

Comment: @NigelRen I corrected it before your comment :P My PHP is just an example, it's not really important the syntax as of now but thank you.

Comment: This needs more explanation with an example - `then it stays if nothing below fits else it gets deleted`.

Comment: @vivek_23 if no other conditions below that condition on my exemple fits then this condition stays, else it gets deleted if another condition situated below it is detected. The exemple is already there :)

Comment: @gumakettell Loop from bottom to top instead of top to bottom. Example ain't clear. You need to show input and output based on the sample data that you showed which covers all `8+`,`3+` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what your conditions are, but to me it looks like you really are giving a rank to each of your rows, where in the end you want to keep the row with the highest rank.

Even if my interpretation of your rules might not be exactly what you intended, you can tune it by adapting the scores in the code below. I would also suggest to swap the conditions so that the `==` comparison comes first. That will be a bit more efficient:

```
$keepKey = null;
$bestScore = -1;
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    $score = 0;
    if ($v[1] == 1 && $v[0] == 1) $score = 1;
    if ($v[1] == 2 && $v[0] >= 2) $score = 2;
    if ($v[1] == 3 && $v[0] >= 6) $score = 3;
    if ($v[1] == 4 && $v[0] >= 8) $score = 4;
    // ... etc ...
    if ($score > $bestScore) {
        $keepKey = $k;
        $bestScore = $score;
    }
}

$sub_array = [$keepKey => $array[$keepKey]]; // Only keep the entry with highest score
```

If it is important to really pick a random one in case of ties, then shuffle the keys before starting the loop:

```
$keepKey = null;
$bestScore = -1;

$keys = array_keys($array); // <---
shuffle($keys);             // <
foreach($keys as $k) {      // <
    $v = $array[$k];        // <---
    $score = 0;
    if ($v[1] == 1 && $v[0] == 1) $score = 1;
    if ($v[1] == 2 && $v[0] >= 2) $score = 2;
    if ($v[1] == 3 && $v[0] >= 6) $score = 3;
    if ($v[1] == 4 && $v[0] >= 8) $score = 4;
    echo $score . "\n";       
    if ($score > $bestScore) {
        $keepKey = $k;
        $bestScore = $score;
    }
}

$sub_array = [$keepKey => $array[$keepKey]];
```